# Testing for null without affecting C# 8 nullable analyzer

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

With C# 8 nullable enabled, the following code generates no errors.

```
var x = GetObjectX();
return x;
```

By adding one line I get a warning:

```
var x = GetObjectX();
Debug.Assert(x != null);
return x; //Warning: 'X' may be null here. Possible null reference return.
```

Is this an expected behavior?

The reason I don't trust the nullable algorithm without the Debug line is because the object returned is deserialized.

What's the cleanest way to suppress the warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In .NET Core 3, `Debug.Assert` is annotated with `[DoesNotReturnWhen(false)]`, which helps the compile understand the code and avoid the warning.

Without it, the compiler sees the null test as an indication from the user that the value could have been null after all.

You can make your own assertion method if you’re not using .NET Core 3. See [`RoslynDebug.Assert`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Compilers/Core/Portable/InternalUtilities/Debug.cs) as an example.

Comment: Thanks, my project was running .NET Core 3 but these lines of code were in a library referencing netstandard 2.0 where Debug.Assert doesn't have this attribute.
I moved the same code from the library to the main project and the warning does not show there.

Answer (score 5):

Try the [null forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) `!`
It can be used when you know, better than the compiler, that a nullable variable will not be null at runtime.

```
var x = GetObjectX();
Debug.Assert(x != null);
return x!;
```